# Convert sequential numbers into single column with missing values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a list of sample ids for a site in the format of:
Sitename, Sample Number such that there is n number of sample numbers for a given site. For example, the data could be:

```
site1 | 1
site1 | 2
```

etc to an arbitrary n.

Using the following as a similar example, this data below would get the answer from the last select statement:

```
CREATE TABLE #SiteWithId(SiteId VARCHAR(50), SampleNumber INT)

INSERT INTO #SiteWithId
(
    SiteId,
    SampleNumber
)
values 
(   'test', -- SiteId - varchar(50)
    1  -- SampleNumber - int
    ),
    ('test',2),
    ('test',3),
    ('test',4),
    ('test',6),
    ('test',7)

    SELECT * FROM #SiteWithId
    DROP TABLE #SiteWithId
    --the answer
    SELECT 'test', '1-4,6-7'
```

Note, that the missing item creates a break in the final answer.

I know I can loop through the dataset in C# and create such an item. But does anyone know to create such a value using only sql so I can just spit out the needed values for the report? I think I could do a loop in sql too but I am scared it would be unscalable since that is not really what sql is made to do.

Is there a better way to do this other than a loop in sql or c#?

Comment: No need for loops.  This seems to be a rather small task using a Numbers/Tally table (or even an ad-hoc Tally Table).  HOWEVER, I don't understand how your data is structured.   Stings ? Rows?  Some formatting would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution that relies on window functions. The difference between the `SampleNumber` of a record and its `ROW_NUMBER()` within groups of records having the same `SiteName` gives you the group it belongs to. Then, the outer query aggregates each group:

```
SELECT SiteName, CONCAT(MIN(SampleNumber), '-', MAX(SampleNumber)) SampleRange
FROM (
    SELECT 
        SiteName, 
        SampleNumber, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SiteName ORDER BY SampleNumber) rn
    FROM mytable
) x
GROUP BY SiteName, (SampleNumber - rn)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6e046c5f98b8a1e815302fe97cbc50c2)**:

Sample data:

```
SiteName | SampleNumber
:------- | -----------:
site1    |            1
site1    |            2
site1    |            3
site1    |            5
site1    |            6
site1    |            8
site1    |            9
site1    |           10
```

Results:

```
SiteName | SampleRange
:------- | :----------
site1    | 1-3        
site1    | 5-6        
site1    | 8-10
```

---

If you  want all the ranges of each site concatenated in one record, you can add another level of aggregation and use `STRING_AGG()` (available since SQL Server 2017):

```
SELECT SiteName, STRING_AGG(SampleRange,',') SampleRange
FROM (
    SELECT SiteName, CONCAT(MIN(SampleNumber), '-', MAX(SampleNumber)) SampleRange
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            SiteName, 
            SampleNumber, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SiteName ORDER BY SampleNumber) rn
        FROM mytable
    ) x
    GROUP BY SiteName, (SampleNumber - rn)
) y
GROUP BY SiteName
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=458995773a1fb014e7db3d9e73d54a4f)**:

```
SiteName | SampleRange 
:------- | :-----------
site1    | 1-3,5-6,8-10
```